# Regarding conversion of object into string in android

Tags: android, pdf-generation, object-to-string

I have 1 class which includes a table consisting of 9 rowa and 9 columns.Table consists of header,value section and footer which includes total of all the data addition.I want to generate pdf for this table.I am taking a commonlayout object and adding row object,values object and footer object in this "commonlayout" object.Can you please tell me how can i convert this object into string which contains all the rows,values and footer section of table.

Comment: **"I have 1 class..."** - What is this class? **"I am taking a commonlayout object..."** - What is a "commonlayout object"? Show your code for the class and the layout.

Comment: override toString() method and implement it.

Comment: @Squonk hmm means in 1 class i implementd this all.commonlayout  object means i have to show all these values in table form.So i take a tablelayout object and add all these other 3 object combinedly in a tableLayout.

Comment: @ChuKoNu hey i override toString() but it gives me 0 values of all items.

Comment: Please show the code.

Comment: **"hmm means in 1 class i implementd this"** - But what type of class is it? Is it a POJO or does it extend an Android class such as `Activity`? Without seeing your code it's unlikely anyone can help you.

Comment: squonk it is Activity!!